# How do I determine the cause of a ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:15:1: unexpected indentation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have a rails app and I had to revert a lot of commits. Now, when I try to view the app locally `localhost:3000`, I get an error I haven't seen before.

```
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
  Rendering layout layouts/lmt.html.erb
  Rendering main/index.html.erb within layouts/lmt
  Event Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events"
  ↳ app/views/main/index.html.erb:14
  Rendered main/index.html.erb within layouts/lmt (Duration: 357.4ms | Allocations: 238507)
  Rendered layout layouts/lmt.html.erb (Duration: 357.6ms | Allocations: 238584)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 358ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Allocations: 239010)
 
ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxError: [stdin]:15:1: unexpected indentation):
  
(execjs):7539:8
(execjs):7557:14
(execjs):1:32
```

In the browser, I click the `Full Trace` link and I see the below output.  It shows the `execjs` lines above, but I've never touched that file and don't know where it is.

I read a couple threads that were more target oriented, like `CoffeeScripts` or `python` and one or two mentioned that it might be an editor issue. I use `sublime-text`

```
SyntaxError: [stdin]:15:1: unexpected indentation

Rails.root: /home/jdc44/Websites/LMT
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
compile ((execjs):7528:19)
eval (eval at <anonymous> ((execjs):7539:8), <anonymous>:1:10)
(execjs):7539:8
(execjs):7557:14
(execjs):1:32
Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:50)
Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:40:in `exec'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:22:in `eval'
execjs (2.9.1) lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:47:in `call'
coffee-script (2.4.1) lib/coffee_script.rb:78:in `compile'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:24:in `block in call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cache.rb:92:in `fetch'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/coffee_script_processor.rb:23:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:22:in `block in <class:CompositeProcessor>'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:33:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:184:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:339:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:207:in `block in fetch_or_store'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:187:in `fetch'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:206:in `fetch_or_store'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:41:in `block in call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:175:in `dfs'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:42:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:184:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:339:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:207:in `block in fetch_or_store'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:187:in `fetch'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:206:in `fetch_or_store'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:32:in `block in call'
/home/jdc44/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/set.rb:511:in `each_key'
/home/jdc44/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.1/lib/ruby/3.1.0/set.rb:511:in `each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:31:in `call'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:84:in `call_processor'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:66:in `block in call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `reverse_each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:65:in `call_processors'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:184:in `load_from_unloaded'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:59:in `block in load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:339:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/loader.rb:43:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `block in load'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:207:in `block in fetch_or_store'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:187:in `fetch'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/map.rb:206:in `fetch_or_store'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:44:in `load'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:81:in `find_asset'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/base.rb:88:in `find_all_linked_assets'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `each'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `to_a'
sprockets (4.2.1) lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in find'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `block in synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/synchronization/mutex_lockable_object.rb:48:in `synchronize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:22:in `execute'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promise.rb:564:in `block in realize'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
concurrent-ruby (1.2.2) lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
```

EDITED TO ADD THIS:

I found a coffeescript file that was changed, although I don't think I did it knowingly.  I do not know CoffeeScript.  I pulled the contents of the changed file from git. Not sure if the indenting shown in git is what it actually was. Would someone who knows CoffeeScript know how it should be formatted?

```
# app/assets/javascript/packs/application.coffee

setup = ->

  $(document).foundation();

$ ->

  console.log "Loading page...!  " + Date.now()%10000

  setup()

  document.addEventListener "turbolinks:load", () ->

  console.log "turbolinks:load "  + Date.now()%10000

    setup()
```

Comment: You can easily check using something like https://coffeelint.github.io/ which will explain the errors where they arise. For instance if I paste your code it says: *"Line #4:Line contains a trailing semicolon"* and
*"Line #16:[stdin]:16:1: error: unexpected indentation setup() ^^^^"* (the 4 ^ indicates the level of indentation e.g. 4 spaces). I would assume the `console.log` line should be indented 4 spaces as well although I am uncertain why you are calling the setup function twice.

Comment: The code in this file did not come from me.  It had to have been something rails did in setup.  Thanks for the pointer to the url for code-checking. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means your COFFEE-SCRIPT file has an incorrect indentation.

CoffeeScript uses indentations to open/close functions, so you cannot indent improperly.

Best suggestion is to see which coffee file you most recently edited and start debugging.

Visit https://coffeescript.org/#try and paste the code onto the left side.

[image: your coffeescript code error]

Comment: Thanks, I edited my initial post to add the contents of a `application.coffee` file that was somehow changed. I have no practical experience with CoffeeScript, so I don't know how it should be formatted/indented.  Looking for others...